# Посоветуйте CMS для сайта

Tags: cms

Добрый день. Посоветуйте самую простую CMS.

Основные требования:

- Размещать статью, возможность прикреплять файл к ней. Ограничивать доступ к файлам. Только зарегистрированные могут скачать.
- Регистрация, авторизация.
- Меню сверху, может иметь много категорий.
- Поиск по статьям.
- Несложна в редактировании кода.
- Бесплатная.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

**Drupal**  https://www.drupal.org/

1. Легко настраивается, русифицируется.
2. Огромное количество существующих бесплатных модулей и бесплатных тем оформления.
3. Описанный Вами функционал можно реализовать без редактирования кода.
4. Дружелюбное русскоязычное сообщество, http://www.drupal.ru/
5. Практически на любой каприз можно найти статью или даже видео
   инструкцию из серии "как сделать... как использовать..." CMS очень
   популярна.

Друпалу под силу любая задача, разве что в магазин за пивом его послать нельзя.

Из минусов как и у всех CMS прожорливость, но она решается кешированием.

Для редактирования кода принято создавать отдельные модули с понятной друпалу структурой (править существующие самостоятельно - плохая идея в плане обновления новых версий движка и модулей). Но структура у модулей простая, на ее изучение уйдет минут 15, за то в коде порядок.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что подойдет [WordPress](https://ru.wordpress.org/).

> Размещать статью, возможность прикреплять файл к ней.

Есть.

> Ограничивать доступ к файлам. Только зарегистрированные могут скачать.

Наверняка можно сделать с помощью плагинов, коих огромное количество.

> Регистрация, авторизация.

Есть.

> Меню сверху, может иметь много категорий.

Темы настраиваются, раньше это было даже в теме по умолчанию. В последних версиях тема по умолчанию изменилась, вроде категории стали размещаться слева, но тем для WordPress написано такое количество, что по этому поводу тоже можно не беспокоиться.

> Поиск по статьям.

Есть.

> Несложна в редактировании кода.

Есть визуальный редактор и редактор HTML.

> Бесплатная.

Да. Хотя есть платные плагины и темы.